# Can Some give an elaborate example of using Custom Jasmine Reporter for protractor. I am unable to understand Tutorial

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

Can Some give an elaborate example of using Custom Jasmine Reporter . I would like someone to help me with a sample test with two assertions . how to add the reporter  in protractor conf.js and how it can help me . No where in the internet there is a example apart from just the reference .

Answer (score 0):

check the one I use:
First check if all the necessary dependencies are installed (check the begin of the code)
Then copy+paste this to you Conf.js:

```
//In my case I installed the dependencies locally thats why comes from lib folder
var jasmineReporters = require('./lib/node_modules/jasmine-reporters');
var HTMLReport = require('./lib/node_modules/protractor-html-reporter-2');
var fs = require('./lib/node_modules/fs-extra');

onPrepare: function () {

fs.emptyDir('./Execution_Results/reports/xml/', function (err) {
  if (err != ""){
    console.log(err);
  }
});

fs.emptyDir('./Execution_Results/reports/results/screenshots', function (err) {
  if (err != ""){
    console.log(err);
  }
});

  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
    consolidateAll: true,
    savePath: './Execution_Results/reports/xml/',
    filePrefix: 'xmlresults'
  }));

  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({
    specDone: function (result) {
        //if (result.status == 'failed') {
      browser.getCapabilities().then(function (caps) 
      {
        var browserName = caps.get('browserName');

        browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
          var stream = fs.createWriteStream('./Execution_Results/reports/results/screenshots/' + browserName + '-' + result.fullName + '.png');
          stream.write(new Buffer(png, 'base64'));
          stream.end();
        });
      });
        //}
    }
});


},

//HTMLReport called once tests are finished
onComplete: function() {
var browserName, browserVersion;
var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();

capsPromise.then(function (caps) {
  browserName = caps.get('browserName');
  browserVersion = caps.get('version');
  platform = caps.get('platform');

    testConfig = {
            reportTitle: 'Protractor Test Execution Report',
            outputPath: './',
            outputFilename: 'Execution_Results/reports/results/IV2_Test_Results',
            screenshotPath: './screenshots/',
            testBrowser: browserName,
            browserVersion: browserVersion,
            modifiedSuiteName: false,
            screenshotsOnlyOnFailure: true,
            testPlatform: platform
    };
    new HTMLReport().from('./Execution_Results/reports/xml/xmlresults.xml', testConfig);
});
},

jasmineNodeOpts: {
showColors: true, // Use colors in the command line report.
// If true, display spec names.
isVerbose: true,
},
```

the folders will be created automatically inside the folder where your conf.js is located so after the execution just access the 'Execution_Results/reports' and open the html report

OnPrepare will generate the xml file with all the results
OnComplete will transform the xml into html report

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to prepare a Jasmine cutom reporter, you have only discussed about using in confg file

Comment: I want to know how to build a custom jasmine reporter, I know that we can use it in Conf.js , but no where there is an example of how it works , Like i want to know how a sample test can be built and how it works when custom jasmine reporter is called etc .

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this reporter, Just follow the steps from this link to set the conf.js  https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter